# Azure WebJob Running after Deleted and Web App Stopped

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

We are testing a new WebJob to run some background processes in a Azure Web Service. The WebJob has a TimerTrigger and runs every 1 minute.

We are in early stages of development, so all the code does right now is log to our database every time it runs.

We saw records being inserted into our database so we deleted the WebJob to test a couple other things. We found that records continued to be inserted into the database after deleting the WebJob via the Portal. We proceeded to Stop the App Service entirely, but still records continued to be inserted into the database.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76019966/deleted-a-triggered-webjob-but-function-still-running-continuously) suggested checking for activity via the azure cli, however, an empty array is returned (same if we swap 'triggered' for 'continuous'):

```
az webapp webjob triggered list --name my-app-name --resource-group my-rg-name
```

The WebJob has been deleted & the Azure App Service has been stopped for about an hour now and still we are getting records inserted into the database every minute.

Our program is not much more complicated than the .NET Core examples offered [here (GitHub Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions)

We have a simple Program.cs:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder();
builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
{
    b.AddTimers();
});
builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
{
    b.AddConsole();
});

var host = builder.Build();
using (host)
{
    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

Functions.cs

```
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger logger)
{
    var connection = _db.Connection;
    await connection.ExecuteAsync("INSERT INTO webjob_logs VALUES ('test', GETDATE())");
}
```

Settings.job

```
{
  "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
}
```

**Update**

After redeploying the webjob & restarting the web app but it is still running the old code:
[image: WebJob from Azure Portal]

Also, not sure if this is related, but I am seeing this in the WebJob Details:
[image: WebJob Details]

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of the Azure WebJob in App Service?

Comment: There might be some cache issues or any other instance of teh process might be running.Try to redeploy the app and check again.

Comment: @Harshitha, I updated the code to insert the value 'test2' into the database so I would know the update took effect, & redeployed, but it is till logging 'test' every minute, not 'test2'.

Comment: Please share the screen shot of your functions and job in portal.

Comment: It means that the job has been deleted, but instance is running from somewhere.

Comment: @Harshitha, I posted a screenshot of the WebJob after I just redeployed it (the version I just deployed should be logging 'test2', but it is logging 'test'.

Comment: Do you have the AzureWebJobsDashboard configuration set in your application as mentioned in the last screenshot.

Comment: Configuration is missing

Comment: @Harshitha We are not using Azure Storage at all for the WebJob. Is it required for the WebJob to run properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255144/discussion-between-harshitha-and-bryceby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have few options to delete a running Web Job.

One is manual deletion.

And the other is by using Azure CLI command which you have already done by following my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76019966/deleted-a-triggered-webjob-but-function-still-running-continuously).

And one more option is to delete the entire files which are uploaded while creating a Web Job.

Whenever a Web Job is created a new folder with name `Jobs` will be created in KUDU Console `site/wwwroot/App_Data` folder.

[image]

- It contains all the Jobs with required `exe/pdb/dll` files related to the WebJob.

[image]

- Delete the entire folder with specific WebJob Name which you want to delete.

Sometimes even after deleting the WebJobs, the jobs will be running in background without our Knowledge.

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#manage-webjobs), set the key `WEBJOBS_STOPPED` with value `1` in the App Service Application Settings to stop the WebJobs.

[image]

Thanks @[IKriKan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69528487/19648279) for the hint.

If you still have any issues with the Web Jobs, you can check the Job details in
`Diagnose and solve problems` => `Availability and Performance` => `WebJob Details`

[image]